# Action Bar Launch-Intent Behaviour with Multiple Menu Items

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple application that allows the user to take a photo using the dispatchTakePictureIntent() that saves the full-size photo; indicated here;  http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskCaptureIntent. And launched using a Camera icon from the action bar. The user then takes a photo presses ok and their picture appears in a list created using a class extending BaseAdapter

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

If I launch the intent as above then everything seems to work fine but I have no response to the delete all button (clicking it would ofc just start the camera intent)

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_photo : {
            if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        }
        case (R.id.action_delete) : {
            deleteAllPhotos();
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

However when setup like this I can delete the photos, but the previously taken photo dissapears every time I click the camera icon to take a new photo

Is there any subtle change in lifecycle or anything introduced by this difference? As I am struggling to find how it can cause this different behaviour.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a break or return statement after your case, so it launches the intent and then deletes all of your previous photos since case statements fall thru to the next one if not told to break.

Try:

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_photo:
        ...
        break;
    case R.id.action_delete:
        ...
        break;
}
```